# What is the result of ${VAR:=value} in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm looking at several bash scripts that use `:=` in between `${ }`. For example, the pattern looks like this:

```
export VAR=${VAR:=value}
```

What is this doing?
Is it assigning **value** to **VAR** if **VAR** does not exist?

Comment: FYI, the `export` isn't necessary unless you want subprocesses to see this value. A more typical usage is `: "${var:=value}"` (yes, lower-case -- all-uppercase names are by convention reserved for environment variables and builtins). `:` is a noop, so the only side effects are those of the `:=` parameter expansion, which doesn't only conditionally expand, but modifies `var` itself if appropriate.

Comment: ...more on that conventional/typical usage: The quotes are there for two reasons: First, they prevent the shell from doing unnecessary work (string-splitting and glob-expanding a value which will be discarded); second, they ensure that if you're using `set -x`, you see a value which hasn't been modified by such expansions, giving you better information when debugging.

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 for more on parameter expansion in general.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "var=${var:-word}" and "var=${var:=word}"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404696/what-is-the-difference-between-var-var-word-and-var-var-word)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> ${parameter:=word}
>
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned to parameter. The value of  parameter is then substituted. Positional parameters and special parameters may not be assigned to in this way.

So it exports the VAR value with its value, or if it is unset/null it is exported with literal `value`.

Answer (score 5):

From the man page:

> ```
>    ${parameter:=word}
>           Assign Default Values.  If  parameter  is  unset  or  null,  the
>           expansion of word is assigned to parameter.  The value of param‐
>           eter is then substituted.   Positional  parameters  and  special
>           parameters may not be assigned to in this way.
> ```

In other words, it basically lets you specify a default value for a variable. If the variable is unset/null, then it will be set to that value and the value will be used as the expansion as well.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Then its current value is used and the variable is unchanged.

Comment: so it replaces the previous value(exists or not) with the current one.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: No. It only replaces it if the variable is unset/null, hence the term "default value". The value is only ever used if the variable is unset.

Answer (score 2):

It's one way to assign a default value to a name.

```
${foo:=bar}
```

will expand to `$foo` if set. Otherwise, it assigns the value `"bar"` to the name `foo` as well as expanding the entire expression to that value. I've never actually seen this used in any good example in real life. I've seen it used like this:

```
: ${foo:=bar}
```

Which works by doing the assignment, but discarding its output. I don't consider that a good example, because you could as easily write

```
foo=${foo:-bar}
```

and I think that's more obvious to most readers.